# Capturing text from UITextfield after UIButton tap

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a few UITextFields embedded inside a UITableView and my UIViewController class is also setup as as UITextFieldDelegate. I have no direct references to the UITextFields in ViewController class and they're only accessible by accessing the specific UITableView's cell at a given NSIndexPath.

Whenever UIButton's action target is invoked due to user tapping on it, '`-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`. for the last active field isn't yet invoked. How do I capture the text in the last active field?

I've tried setting flags to note start and end of editing as well as a few other solutions, but none of these seem right..

Inside my onButtonTap action handler, if I had this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES]; 
// would the call to 'textFieldDidEndEditing' happen synchronously and then return
// to this line or would they be async?
[self doActionLogic]; //
```

Can anyone suggest a good technique to do this? Seems like it would be a standard problem but I'm just a little slow on figuring out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you only need the input of the textfield you can set the test to a ivar in the method and return yes.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

textFieldDidEndEditing could be called after the button action but since you have already have it in ivar there will be no problem.But the best approach is, you could check the input of the textfield an enable the button in

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

so enable your unbutton whenever you have a valid input inside the uitexfield.shouldChangeCharactersInRange is called as you typed something and before the input is inserted to uitextfield.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your suggestions. I am saving the textField.text value when 'textFieldShouldEndEditing' is invoked. What you're saying is to always disable the UIButton as soon as the button tap event arrives and the enable the UIButton whenever shouldChangeCharactersInRange is invoked?

Comment: I've clarified my question a bit further.

Comment: if you save the value before textfieldshouldendEditing it is good.Don#t you have the value already set when the action triggers?Hwy do you have end editing inside your button action class?

Comment: The *problem* is that textFieldShouldEndEditing won't get called until after the UIButton's target is called. So at the time the button's action is processed, what I have saved does not reflect the current contents of the UITextField.

Comment: in that case update your ivar with textfield content in shouldChangeCharactersInRange not inside textFieldShouldEndEditing which is called after button action.You have to append the replacement string to your NSmutablestring ivar to hold the value.In this case you will always  have the latest value

Comment: shouldChangeCharactersInRange would be invoked countless times - that seems not as performant with all of the appending per character to the ivar.